# Safely removing sodium hypochlorite crystals from hard-to-reach surfaces

Tags: solutions, home-experiment, ionic-compounds

I have a small bathing whirlpool which wasn’t used for over ten years. It is built into the ground and I cannot reach the disinfectant container to replace it with a new one. I can access the fill-pipe for the disinfectant which read „Sodium Hypoclorid“ at the time of the last disinfection.

When I open the 1 cm-wide diameter pipe to fill the disinfectant in, I see a layer of half-transparent salt-like material, thus my question:

Assuming that the disinfectant within the container is solid, is there some (safe) method where I can add some special solvent and then rinse the whole container so these crystals go away?

Comment: Your substance  should have been written "Sodium hypochlorite", and not "sodium hypchlorid". This substance exists only in the dissolved state. It can not be obtained at the solid state. It gets decomposed if you try. So your crystals are not sodium hypochlorite.  Next question : what are they ? Are they soluble into water ? Is it not easier to simply rub them out of the tube, instead of finding an acidic or an oxidizing solution ?

Comment: Sodium hypochlorite can be solid, but is unstable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hypochlorite

Comment: So Onelight has not obtained any crystals of sodium hypochlorite in his pool

Comment: I have only very, very little background in chemistry- so sorry for that - I am here to learn.

Comment: only one side of the fill-pipe to the disinfectant container is accessible. The inside of the disinfectant container is not accessible. So filling something in would be the best method. Sorry accidentally mixed german word „Chlorid“ and the english one.

Comment: Are the crystal pentahydrate NaOCl·5H2O ? How to solve them?! Have that one from wikipedia. Hope you guys know better.

Comment: The special solvent you want is water

Comment: yea but water doesn’t seem to do the job to make this material liquid again. I assume hot water can do the job - is it save because of the chlorine?

Comment: Thanks @Waylander. Is it enough to fill in water and then wait for 1-2 days? Will the material resolve itself in the water? Thank You!

Comment: What you are creating is bleach solution. Handle it like you would a bottle of clorox

Answer (score 0):

Standard [sodium hypochlorite disinfecting bleach](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28722950/#:%7E:text=Bleach%20contains%203%25%20to%208,which%20are%20not%20covered%20here.) is a mixture of $\ce{NaOCl}$, $\ce{NaCl}$, and $\ce{NaOH}$. The sodium hydroxide, also known as lye and caustic soda, is employed to capture $\ce{CO2}$ that can lower pH via carbonic acid. The latter product reacts with hypochlorite forming the more active and unstable hypochlorous acid $\ce{HOCl}$, that has an even much reduced shelf life than hypochlorite.

Now, why $\ce{NaCl}$, because the [commercial preparation of chlorine bleach](https://www.serviceindustrynews.net/2021/05/14/history-of-chlorine-production-and-use/) is from the action of chlorine on $\ce{NaOH}$, producing equal amounts of both $\ce{NaOCl}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$.

With time, the present of even dust particles with traces amount of transition metals will breakdown the $\ce{NaOCl}$ into $\ce{NaCl}$ and some problematic $\ce{NaClO3}$ (chlorate).

Since this is evidently very aged bleach, the only problematic residual compound is the chlorate. To remove the latter, the less messy dry route is to mildly heat with a small blow torch, as to quote [a source](https://www.angelfire.com/ok2/kelouise/excel/DecompSodiumChlorate.pdf):

> Sodium chlorate, NaClO3, is a colorless, odorless, white solid that melts at 248°C. When heated above 300°C, it begins to lose oxygen. The ultimate products of the thermal decomposition of sodium chlorate are oxygen gas and a white solid.

where the white solid is yet more $\ce{NaCl}$.

Other paths include the use of liquid sulfuric acid, methanol,..., and there is an associated release of toxic/explosive chlorine dioxide $\ce{ClO2}$, which is a path best avoided, in my opinion.

After the heat treatment, just collect the dry salt or water hose it away.

Some references, on the [decomposition of hypochlorite](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/chlorate) and [also comments here](https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v56-068).